# Why should i resize uploaded images

Tags: php, image, resize

I have a script that uploads images,renames them and stores the relative filepath in my database.As i was coding the script however, i came across the topic of image resizing, but i could not find a reason as to why i should resize images.

Currently, i simply store the image that the user uploads as long as it is smaller than my specified file size(2MB).As i display the images, i simply "resize" them to fit my dimensions using

```
<img src="../filepath/" height=100px width=100px />
```

and the image is "resized" to my specified dimensions of 100px by 100px, and i'm not having any issues with it currently. If the need ever arises where i need a bigger image size, i would just change the height and width to the needed size.

**Question:**

- What is image resizing
- What does it do
- Why should i resize iamges before uploading them
- What are it's advantages

I'm rather new to programming and i apologise in advance for the questions if it's a really stupid question with obvious answers

Comment: If you're using height and width attributes to resize the image, then you're still sending the fullsize image to the user, and letting their browser re-size it. Assume that you have 50 images on a page, all of which a 2 megs apiece - that's 100 megs of images you're sending to the user. If you resize them so they're 100x100, and send the re-sized images, you're going to be sending a fraction of that.

Comment: You're not resizing the images with the `height`/`width` stuff. you're still still making your users download the FULL-sized image. it'll just be DISPLAYED as a 100x100 image. e.g. if the original image is a 4096x4096 10meg file. your user downloads 10meg of data, and then shoves it all into a postage-stamp sized box. Your bandwidth will be HORRENDOUS, and your users will hate the site because it takes FOREVER to load the image pages.

Comment: @MarcB Hi Marc thanks for taking the time to answer, however i've seen in some examples here that people who resize their images, resize them to different sizes(e.g thumbnail, small size, mid size, etc) and keep them all on their server. In this case, wouldn't it be better to simply store one big image and use the height and width as the situation demands?

Comment: nope. processing images is a heavy cpu/memory requirement. If you keep the original, and dynamically resize the image on the server to fit whatever the client needs, e.g. `<img src="pic.php?id=foo&width=100&height=100">` your server has to decompress that image (huge memory requirement), resize it to whatever the specified size is (huge cpu requirements), recompress to jpg, and shoot that "new" image out the door. Then it THROWS AWAY that smaller file, and does it over and over again. A total waste of cpu/memory capacity.

Comment: by doing the resizing ONCE, ahead of time, you only pay the cpu/memory overhead that one time, and pay a bit extra in disk space (very cheap these days). You also massively save on bandwidth, by sending out a 10k "small" image v.s. a 10meg "original" image.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for taking the time to reply, would you like to post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @ken: it's basically what Joe answered below. he should get credit.

Comment: The term for resizing images in the browser will still making the poor user download the entire large image is "dumbnail."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for image resizing is to save space. Images take up a lot of space. For example, an image can be anywhere between 10kb and 20mb, or more.

This has a huge impact on website load time. If an image is of a 2048 x 2048 resolution, but you are only displaying a 60 x 60 resolution, then you are serving a huge amount of image that you do not need. Serving an image the size of 60 x 60 could save around 10mb or so of space (well, maybe not that much, but you get the idea!) (depending on the image).

If you have a lot of images on a page, this adds up, so if your images are scaled to the right size, then your page load time would be much much faster.

Another plus side is it reduces bandwidth usage, so you can save some cash when paying for bandwidth from your host!

Hope this helps!